# Limit class duration

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a WinForms program with a sign in system. On sign in, a class called `session` is created. This holds all information relevant to the sign in (much like the name "session" indicates).

Now I would like for this session to only have a limited duration. So after, lets say 30 minutes, the class destroys itself (or its parent does, that's not important).

How do I do this? I have tried searching Google, but apparently keywords like "Duration" and "Timespan" returns results which is in no way related to what I want to do.

Comment: start a timer from the login, and when the timer event fires, close the form.

Comment: The form is the main window itself, which should not be closed. It should simply close the session class (set it to  `null`) and return to the login screen.

Comment: @Noceo seems like you've just answered your original question :)

Comment: Your approach doesn't seem well chosen to me. What you should do instead of destroying the **instance** (you do not destroy a class), is **modifying** it each time you want it to be invalidated

Comment: @ArthurAttout I am not sure i quite understand. Though I agree that I am of course not destryoing the class (just the instance), I don't understand what you mean with "...modifying it each time you want it to be invalidated"?

Comment: @Noceo Maybe set some sort of authentication token to null or something like that, forcing them to login again but preserving the session

Comment: That might actually be a good idea, in order to avoid data loss.

Comment: @Noceo - do you want to close the session even if the user is still active?

Comment: All your questions has pointed out some not-so-well-designed features of my initial idea. The best solution would probably be a inactive timer. But if that becomes too complicated, I could probably make do, with a solution where the sign-in token died, and needed to be renewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Interval` timer tick with interval which start `EventHandler` every `N` seconds (you can start it once and do your job)

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer updateTimer;

    public Form1()
    {
        updateTimer = new Timer();
        updateTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(FixedUpdate);
        updateTimer.Interval = 30000; //Time in miliseconds (30 seconds)
        updateTimer.Start();
    }


    private void FixedUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Destroy your form first time it thicks after N time
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this the best pracitice for session timers as well? It does look a little bit ridicolous with a 3,600,000 ms (1 hour) timer :-)

Comment: Why you think that? It will start function after 1hr so it is all cool :)

Comment: It does work indeed. I just wasn't sure if this approach were more suited for shorter timers. But what the heck :-)